# DocumentDB filter documents on multiple items in a child array

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DB database with documents that have the following form:

```
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Price": 200,
  "Properties": [
    {
        "Name": "Name1",
        "Type": "Type1",            
    },
    {
        "Name": "Name2",
        "Type": "Type2",            
    }
  ]
},
{
  "Id": "2",
  "Price": 500,
  "Properties": [
    {
        "Name": "Name1",
        "Type": "Type1",            
    },
    {
        "Name": "Name2",
        "Type": "Type3",            
    }
  ]
},
{
  "Id": "3",
  "Price": 400,
  "Properties": [
    {
        "Name": "Name1",
        "Type": "Type2",            
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to create a query that returns documents that satisfy multiple properties. E.g. I would like to retrieve the documents that have both properties of Type1 and Type2. The result should give me only the document with Id = 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.Id
FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Properties, {'Type': 'Type1' }, true)
AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.Properties, {'Type': 'Type2' }, true)
```

Comment: What does the third argument (true) do? I cannot find any documentation on this argument.

Comment: The third boolean parameter is for enabling or disabling partial matching (ie, this property of the object matches but the rest of the object doesn't have to). It doesn't appear to be well documented

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794691/cosmosdb-sql-query-that-matches-multiple-values-in-an-array which was answered by someone directly from the Cosmos team

Comment: Ah ok, I missed that one. It would be nice if this was documented. I tried to add a comment to the documentation page, but that did not work (just says "error")

Comment: We'll get this added to the documentation asap.